# Doctrine find by number match

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a doctrine query builder logic problem which I couldn't solve.

Example:

table users

**id - name - code**

```
1 - test - 10

2 - test2 - 10 B

3 - test3 - 10 C

4 - test4 - 103

5 - test5 - 101
```

I did a query with $code . '%' but this always selects the wrong ones.

```
$bu->setParameter(':code', $code . '%');
```

I want to reach the following result, select codes that match the code **10, 10 B & 10 C**, so only looking to the numbers. So that we get as results back id: 10, 10 B & 10 C.

Only if the code before the space is matching than select it. So that 10 B & 10 C are selected.

I have looked into regex ^[1-9][0-9]*$" but couldn't finish it and add it to the setParameter in doctrine and get the results I wanted.

Any others way to do it? Thanks for the help.

Comment: An alternative to using regex would be adding another criteria to match `$code` exactly, so it would evaluate to `WHERE code = '10' OR code LIKE '10 %'`.

Comment: If you use regular expression, it should be something like this`^[1][0][ ]{0,1}[BC]{0,1}$`. This will return `10`, `10 `, `10B`, `10C`, `10 C`, and `10 B`